# What is MA-contour plots?

Tags: data-visualization, scatterplot

I recently read a paper describe their result with `MA-contour plots`, I did some searches, but most of the information I could get was about the results of `contour plots`, which seemed to be different from the data in the article. Is this a variant of `MA-plot`?

See Figure 2g of https://doi.org/10.1101/2023.08.21.554109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M$ and $A$ are two expressions for microarray fluorescence readouts, specifically the ratio of intensity between two colour channels and the average of both intensities - usually in the log scale. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MA_plot) has a lot of details.

To answer the specific question on the contour, yes, they likely converted a scatter plot into a density. You can see they did the same with more axis annotations in figure 2d, and in both cases the intensity scatter plot (in original scale) is right above the MA contour.

Comment: I have a bit confusing about the contour, I understand that a contour need three axis (X, Y, Z) and convert it to 2D plot, however as a `MA plot`, its seem that we only have two axis?

Comment: The Z is the density at that point, you can calculate it as the number of observations that lie within each cell of an X-Y grid. I'm not sure if there's an `R` function to do it for you but there's bound to be some package out there.